# is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I have this directory structure

```
hosting 
  app 
  database
    Database.php
  view
    index.php
  vendor
    autoload.php
```

and this is the code for index

```
# Load env
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

use \Database\Database as Db;

# database connection
$database = new Db();
d($database);
exit;
```

and this is the content in composer json

```
{
  "name": "Sale App",
  "description": "m.",
  "keywords": ["sale"],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
      "kint-php/kint": "^2.2",
      "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\": "database/"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the partial code for database.php

```
<?php
namespace Database;

class Database extends mysqli
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $dbname = 'abchosting';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pswd = 'password';
    private $log  = true;

    /**
     * make instance of the class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
      d('yes');
      exit;

      parent:: __construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->pswd, $this->dbname);
      $this->set_charset("utf8");

      if ( mysqli_connect_error() )
      {
        if( $this->log )
        error_log( '[ CLASS: Database.php ] [ ERROR: __construct ] Connection error '.$this->gstNameDB.': Error No. ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' : '. mysqli_connect_error());

        die('[ CLASS: Database.php ] [ ERROR: __construct ] Connection error '.$this->gstNameDB.': Error No. ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' : '. mysqli_connect_error());
      }
    }
```

But when view in the chrome, 
it says

```
is currently unable to handle this request.
```

where am I wrong with this simple implementation using namespace and composer?

Comment: Where do you load the vendor/autoload.php file ?

Comment: at index.php in the root directory

Comment: Can you check the logs for more information about the error ?

Comment: Add these lines ini_set("display_errors",1);error_reporting(E_ALL); in starting of your php file and see what errors you re getting

Comment: I just carefully follow what instructed here https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Are you trying to access the application from view/index.php ?

Comment: @Jazz nope. Im trying to access application in index.php in root directory

Comment: Did you cheked the logs ?

Comment: nope.. the only thing I did is to carefully check if the namespace casing

Comment: It's pretty difficult to know what's wrong without the full error message. Please check apache error logs or turn on php error reporting.